# How to Extract digits from string?

Tags: java, string

I need to extract digital values from the below string, basically the values after dollar sign :

```
"Current Revenue Page1 : SP-A-B2Btest
 Current revenue: +$109,852.65
 Previous revenue: +$54,730.12
 Change revenue: +$55,122.53
 % Change revenue: 100.71%"
```

I need to calculate the change revenue by subtracting previous from the current for verification purpose.
Please guide me on this.

Comment: Best way to do this is using a **regular expression**. If you don't know regular expressions yet, now is an excellent time to go online and *learn*.

Comment: What research have you done about parsing numbers? What code did you try?

Comment: I think probably a `DecimalFormat` is a better choice than just regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code.

```
public class RegexExamples {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String str="+$109,852.65";
    String numbers;
     numbers=str.replaceAll("[^0-9.]", "");
    System.out.println("Numbers are: " + numbers);
}}
```

Comment: You can write function and pass string get numbers and use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegEx to find your values (where stringToSearch is your string):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(" ([0-9,.]{2,}) ");   // the pattern to search for
Matcher m = p.matcher(stringToSearch);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(0)); // whole matched expression
    System.out.println(m.group(1)); // first
    System.out.println(m.group(2)); // second 
    System.out.println(m.group(3)); // third 
    System.out.println(m.group(3)); // fourth
}
```

I used the pattern `([0-9,.]{2,})` which selects any number with `.` or `,`, that is 2 or more digits long.